# JMeter howto: same thread group - same variable - different value

Tags: multithreading, parameters, jmeter

I'm doing a performance test on different versions of my application.
The results end up in a csv summary-report.

Is there a way to change the variable correctly for each thread group?

Manual Script:

[image: Manual Script]

Script with variable: ***(not working, help needed)***. 
**I don't want to change the version manually when a version changes**, but only one parameter. Thanks!

[image: Script with variable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [_*P*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [_property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) function in your Thread Group and Sampler names.

Like `Application-${__P(version1,)}`, `Login-${__P(version1,)}`, etc.

Provide property value via 'user.properties' file or via `-J` command-line argument as

```
jmeter -Jversion1=1.0 -Jversion2=2.0 -n -t path_to_your_script.jmx -l path_to_results.jtl
```

All generated reports will contain these properties.

References:

- [How do I run JMeter in non-gui mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)